# creating .jar and FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
```

My code works in ide and i have this file.txt even in all folders of project file. I am exporting the project to jar in 3 different ides(netbeans, intellij idea, eclipse), then i run the jar file but i get this error(double clicking on the jar doesnt unfortunately work on me so i use java -jar on cmd to run);

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (the system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

it works if i give the fullpath of the file in the code but i will send the project to someone else so folder will be changed, when i try solutions like InputStream etc. I get nullpointerexception.

Comment: Could you add your file / folder hierarchy?

Comment: when i open jar by winrar, all classes and files are there. my jar is in project/dist/ and my files are in project/

Comment: The entries in a jar (or zip, which a jar really is underneath) are copied _from_ files, but **aren't files**. The Java classes designed for actual files, like `FileReader`, **don't work** on things that are not files. The 'new' (java 7 ~ 2011!) **`java.nio`** classes on jar/zip entries as well as real files. You can treat both jar entries and files _that are in the CLASSPATH_ as **resources**, and there are hundreds of existing Qs on doing that as well as thousands of tutorials everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using getResourceAsStream is working.

```
InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/komsu.txt");
InputStreamReader iss = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(iss);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
```

Main word of Main.class here is the name of my class name, you can do it like YourClassName.class or directly getClass() method instead of Main.class if you deal with static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "files" folder near your jar and put your files inside it. Try this code block:

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
        + File.separator
        + "files"
        + File.separator + "file.txt";
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```